# Issue in installing devtools in R version 4.0

Tags: r, installation, package, devtools, rtools

After updating the R version from 3.5 to 4.0 I am facing installation issues with devtools package.
Having Rtools 4.0 and RStudio-1.2.5042 downloaded and installed.
when I try to install devtools

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

I get this message:

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently
>   installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of
>   Rtools before proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ Installing package into
>   ‘C:/Users/shalzsab/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) also installing the dependency ‘usethis’
>
> There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
>           binary source needs_compilation usethis  1.6.0  1.6.1             FALSE
>
> trying URL
>   'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/devtools_2.3.0.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 351089 bytes (342 KB) downloaded
>   342 KB
>
> package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>     C:\Users\shalzsab\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkhJwos\downloaded_packages
>   installing the source package ‘usethis’
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/usethis_1.6.1.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 255052 bytes (249 KB)
>   downloaded 249 KB
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘C:\Users\shalzsab\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkhJwos\downloaded_packages’

And when I load the package I get this error

```
library(devtools)
```

> Error: package ‘usethis’ required by ‘devtools’ could not be found

If I try to check the packages in the installation directory

```
find.package("devtools")
```

> "C:/Users/shalzsab/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/devtools"

For usethis package I get this error

```
find.package("usethis")
```

> Error in find.package("usethis") : there is no package called ‘usethis’

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you install the package **usethis**?

Comment: devtools needs usethis, you don't have usethis. You seem to have diagnosed this one by yourself...

Comment: That's strange:  normally `install.packages()` automatically installs all dependencies.  Maybe some packages are out of date?  `devtools` needs `usethis (>= 1.6.0)`.

Comment: I did install usethis, but that gets installed in Temp folder.

Comment: Does `library(usethis)` work?

Comment: No `library(usethis)` does not work. It shows: Error in library(usethis) : there is no package called ‘usethis’

Comment: This problem arose only after I installed the latest version of R (4.0), Rtools (40) and Rstudio (1.2.5042). I found two major issues: 1. The packages that are downloaded in Temp folder are in .rar format, 2. Rstudio don't recognize rtools installed.